# elasticsearch mapping with numeric token

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the mapping below and it works normally

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "stemmer_plural_portugues": {
            "name": "minimal_portuguese",
            "stopwords" : ["http", "https", "ftp", "www"],
            "type": "stemmer"
          },
          
          
            "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "lenient": true,
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",
            "updateable" : true

          },
          
       
          "shingle_filter": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          }

        },
        
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_customizado": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "stemmer_plural_portugues",
              "asciifolding",
              "synonym_filter",
              "shingle_filter"
              
            ],
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        }

      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {

        "id": {
         "type": "long"
        },
         "data": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "quebrado": {
          "type": "byte"
          
        },
         "pgrk": {
           "type":  "integer" 
        },
         "url_length": {
           "type":  "integer" 
        },
        "title": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": {
        "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "url": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I insert the doc below

```
{
    "title": "rocket 1960",
    "description": "space",
    "url": "www.nasa.com"
}
```

If I execute the query below using the AND operator, it will find the doc normally, because all the words searched exist in the doc.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    
    "query": {
      
            
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "space nasa rocket",
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "description",
                        "url"
                    ],
                    "operator": "and"
              }

    }
}
```

but if I put it in the search also "1960" as the query below does not return anything

```
{
        "from": 0,
        "size": 10,
        
        "query": {
          
                
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "1960 space nasa rocket",
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "fields": [
                            "title",
                            "description",
                            "url"
                        ],
                        "operator": "and"
                  }
    
        }
    }
```

I found that my "lowercase" tokenizer does not generate a numeric token. So I change my tokenizer to "standard" and the 1960 numeric token is generated.

but the query does not find anything, because the URL field that has the link [www.nasa.com](http://www.nasa.com) no longer generates the token "www nasa com" the generated token is the entire link [www.nasa.com](http://www.nasa.com).

The query only works if I enter the full URL [www.nasa.com](http://www.nasa.com) as shown below

```
{
            "from": 0,
            "size": 10,
            
            "query": {
              
                    
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "1960 space www.nasa.com rocket",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "fields": [
                                "title",
                                "description",
                                "url"
                            ],
                            "operator": "and"
                      }
        
            }
        }
```

If I generate another "lowercase" tokenizer just for the URL field the link [www.nasa.com](http://www.nasa.com) again generates the separate tokens "www nasa com"

but my query below does not find anything, because the URL field has a different tokenizer than the other fields title and description. The query below only works if I use the OR operator, but I need the AND operator,

```
{
                "from": 0,
                "size": 10,
                
                "query": {
                  
                        
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "1960 space nasa rocket",
                                "type": "cross_fields",
                                "fields": [
                                    "title",
                                    "description",
                                    "url"
                                ],
                                "operator": "and"
                          }
            
                }
            }
```

I cannot use Ngram in my mapping because I use "Phrase Suggester" and when I use Ngram the suggestions are being generated with hundreds of tokens generating inaccuracy in the suggestions.

would anyone know any solution for my mapping to be able to generate numeric tokens in my "title and descripton" fields, but that my URL field will continue with the website links being broken into several tokens "www nasa com" instead of the link being whole "www .nasa.com "and that my query works as an AND operator searching all fields at the same time.

Comment: Can you add your synonyms.txt? I feel that's the problem. Otherwise all works

Comment: @Gibbs my synonyms work normally

Comment: It's not reproducible. That's the only difference I see. Are you saying that contents in the synonyms file do not affects this query.

Comment: @gibbs I just tested removing the synonym from my mapping and nothing changed, the same problem continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I put it in the search also "1960" as the query below does not
> return anything

**In the following Index Mapping, I have removed `synonym_filter`. After removing it and indexing the sample documents, and running the same search query as you mentioned in the question, I am able to get the desired result**

**Index Mapping :**

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "stemmer_plural_portugues": {
            "name": "minimal_portuguese",
            "stopwords": [
              "http",
              "https",
              "ftp",
              "www"
            ],
            "type": "stemmer"
          },
          "shingle_filter": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_customizado": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "stemmer_plural_portugues",
              "asciifolding",
              "shingle_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "quebrado": {
        "type": "byte"
      },
      "pgrk": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "url_length": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "title": {
        "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "description": {
        "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "url": {
        "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "1960 space nasa rocket",
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "description",
        "url"
      ],
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my-index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.9370217,
            "_source": {
                "title": "rocket 1960",
                "description": "space",
                "url": "www.nasa.com"
            }
        }
    ]
```

As stated by @Gibbs, I think there is some issue in `synonym_filter`, so it would be better if you share `synonym.txt` otherwise, the search query is running perfectly.

**Update 1 : (Including synonym_filter)**

**If you want to include Synonym Token Filter then, keep the index mapping same as yours, just making some changes in the mapping which is:**

```
 "synonym_filter": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "lenient": true,
        "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",
        "updateable" : false  --> set this to false

      },
```

> You set your synonym filter to "updateable", presumably because you
> want to change synonyms without having to close and reopen the index
> but instead use the reload API. Updatable synonyms restrict the
> analyzer they are used in to be only used at search time .

To get the full explanation of this, you can refer to this ES [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/synonyms-filter-doesnt-work-in-all-modes-when-indexing/223071)

**Use the same search query as above (after making changes in the mapping
), you will get your desired result.**

But if you still want to set `"updateable" : true`, then you can refer official documentation of [Reload search analyzers API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-reload-analyzers.html#indices-reload-analyzers-api-example)

Comment: @Jean if you put ```"1960"``` in the search query, then also the search result is coming exactly what it should be (after removing synonym_filter). Since the issue is coming at your end when using ```synonym_filter```, it would be great if you can share ```synonym.txt```

Comment: really worked without the synonym. follow my synonym's file link: https://hotbusca.com/synonym.txt

Comment: @Jean please go through my updated answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: Yes! It worked. thank you very much! could you help me with this other problem of the link I send you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616417/phrase-suggester-with-ngrams

Comment: @Jean glad I could be of help here :) It would be great if you can please accept and upvote my answer, as this resolved your issue :)

Comment: @Jean Thank u for giving me info about other question, I am working on that :)

Comment: @Jean can you please upvote this answer as well and I have given the answer of your other question, please check that also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62617399/10348758