# Phrase suggester with ngrams

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

because I use the option "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": true" in the "shingle_filter" filter for in the search for suggestion only show  shingles in the results, but the suggestions display the ngrams

```
        "shingle_filter": {
        "type": "shingle",
        "min_shingle_size": 2,
        "max_shingle_size": 3,
        "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": true
```

Follow below my mapping

```
    {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
   
      
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "stemmer_plural_portugues": {
            "name": "minimal_portuguese",
            "stopwords" : ["http", "https", "ftp", "www"],
            "type": "stemmer"
          },
          
          
       
        "ngram_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
          
        },
            "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "lenient": true,
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",
            "updateable" : false

          },
          
       
          "shingle_filter": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3,
            "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": true
          }

        },
        
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_customizado": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "stemmer_plural_portugues",
              "asciifolding",
                "synonym_filter",
                 "ngram_filter",
                  "shingle_filter"
              
            ],
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        }

      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {

        "id": {
         "type": "long"
        },
         "data": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "quebrado": {
          "type": "byte"
          
        },
         "pgrk": {
           "type":  "integer" 
        },
         "url_length": {
           "type":  "integer" 
        },
        "title": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": {
        "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "url": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  
}
```

I insert the doc below

```
{
    "title": "shopping",
    "description": "sex video",
    "url": "www.ohcs.com"
}
```

In my suggestion query below I type "video" in the wrong way "vidio"

```
    {
  "suggest": {
    "text": "vidio",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "description",
        "size": 1,
        "max_errors": 100,
        "direct_generator": [
          {
          "field" :            "description",
          "suggest_mode" :     "always",
          "min_word_length" :  1
          }
        ],
        "collate": {
          "query": { 
            "source" : {
              "match": {
                "{{field_name}}": {
                  "query": "{{suggestion}}",
                  "operator": "and"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "params": {"field_name" : "description"},
          "prune": true
        },
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<strong>",
          "post_tag": "</strong>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the result below the suggestion search the result displays the correct suggestion "video" but displays and several ngram tokens instead of the entire word

```
    {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "suggest": {
    "simple_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "vidio",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 5,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "vid ide deo",
            "highlighted": "vid <strong>ide deo</strong>",
            "score": 0.2648209,
            "collate_match": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how do I get the results of the suggestion to display the entire word "video" without being divided into several ngram tokens?

Comment: @Bhavya could you help me with this other problem Phrase suggester with ngrams

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your ngram filter. You set min gram as 3 and max gram as 3.

Hence you are gettinf only 3 letter words. You can change max gram to the value you want. In your example if you set to 5, you can get video in your output.

You have as below:

```
    "ngram_filter": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 3,
      "max_gram": 3,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit"
      ]
      
    },
```

Comment: I already did changing to minimum 3 and maximum 5, 10 etc ... and it did not work